# Expesso Store - ratings / reviews add-on?

Tags: expresso-store

Expesso Store

Looking to add a ratings / reviews facility for each product in the Store.

Could anyone recommend an EE Add-on that would be suitable & would 'play nicely' with Expresso Store?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as complete if it answers your question

Answer (score 5):

Since Store uses channel entries to store product details, you can use any EE rating/review modules with it.

Some of the more popular options are:

- [Solspace Rating](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/rating/)
- [DevDemon Channel Ratings](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_ratings/)
- [Solspace Favorites](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/favorites/)

Comment: I personally use DevDemon Channel Ratings when I need rating/review functionality.